# Classic ASP Cookie wont expire

Tags: asp-classic, session-cookies

My DOT NET application is calling a classic asp page (say root/folder1/ABC.asp) which in turn call this following piece of code (i.e. user-Agent is my DOT NET Application).

```
Response.Cookies("TestCookie") = ""
Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Expires = Date() -1
Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Path = "/"
```

when i navigate to following pages, i still see the "TestCookie" in fiddler:-
    root/folder1/1.asp (These requests are originating in the browser.)
    root/folder2/2.asp

Environment : Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found the solution. Finding since Posting the Question: It seems like that problem is due to the User-Agent. First, i manually made the request (which comes from DOT NET App) in the IE, it just worked fine and expires the cookie.) So i created an IE instance in my DOT NET app which was able to access IE cookie-store and expire